# How to remove dark line and gradient under action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

How do i remove this line under the action bar?
[image: actionbar black line]
<sub>(source: [android.com](https://developer.android.com/images/ui/actionbar-dropdown@2x.png))</sub>

I would like it to be a solid color like the way google+ or the below app is:
[image: solid color actionbar bottomline]

i have tried

```
<item name="windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
```

But that doesnt seem to remove it. All i want to do is just use a solid color, no tiled image, no gradient.

Comment: http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/

Comment: Thats the first thing i tried. brilliant application. but it doesnt remove this line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

they this code it is override Background of actiobar

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.actionbar));
```

**drawable/actionbar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >
<solid android:color="#06B697" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the style the ActionBar using the `styles.xml` file in `res/values`
In the theme you are yusing for your app write

```
<item name="android:actionBarStyle>@style/actionBarStyle</item>
```

and add the style `actionBarStyle`

```
<style name="actionBarStyle"
       parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="android:background>Color or drawable you want as background</item>
</style>
```

[Here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html#) is a nice tutorial about this

alternativly, you can style the actionbar programmatically from an activity:

```
getActonBar.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable you want as background);
```